# Can't get excel vba function with two arguments to work

Tags: excel, vba

I have this function in Excel Vba:

```
Function split_std(cell As String, separator As String)

    Dim arr() As String
    arr() = Split(cell, separator)
    MsgBox (arr(0))

End Function
```

And I am calling it this way:

```
Sub split_standard()
Set cell = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select the cell to split", Title:="Cell Selection", Type:=8)
separator = InputBox("Please type in the separator of the items in the string")
Dim arr() As String


MsgBox (cell)

split_std (cell, separator)

End Sub
```

But when finishing writing the call to the function, error: "Expected: =" appears. I already tried by removing brackets, but I can't get it to work. Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Function split_std(cell As String, separator As String)
    Dim arr() As String
    arr() = Split(cell, separator)
    MsgBox (arr(0))
End Function

Sub split_standard()
    Dim cell As String
    Dim separator As String

    cell = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select the cell to split", Title:="Cell Selection", Type:=8)
    separator = InputBox("Please type in the separator of the items in the string")
    MsgBox (cell)

    Call split_std(cell, separator)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Close:

```
Function split_std(cell As String, separator As String)

    Dim arr() As String
    arr() = Split(cell, separator)
    MsgBox (arr(0))

End Function


Sub split_standard()

    Dim cell As Range, separator As String

    Set cell = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select the cell to split", Title:="Cell Selection", Type:=8)
    separator = InputBox("Please type in the separator of the items in the string")
    Dim arr() As String

    MsgBox cell

    split_std CStr(cell.Value), separator

End Sub
```